# Setting up web page width

Tags: html

I am new to web-design. I want to set the page-width so that it appears well in a 800x600 resolution screen. I normally use Tables but I read somewhere that excessive use of Tables slows the performance of the website. What other thing I can use and how to set the width?

Comment: Since you're new to web design, can I say: **Please** don't set up your page to use a fixed width. Computer screens come in a wide variety of sizes, and people like to make their browser window the size *they* want. Fixed-width layouts (like SO, sadly) effectively say to the user: "I don't care what you want, I'm going to do this at X by Y and you'll just have to scroll or change your window size." Yes, it can sometimes make your life easier, but is your site for you, or for your users? A fluid layout (within reason; a minimum width is fine) is much more respectful and not that much harder.

Comment: IMHO it's a matter of taste and use case. Which sense does it make when you have a fluid layout in terms of dynamic width when your text columns are 1900px wide? Hard to read. And in case you have image buttons etc. it's hard to scale. So I think it depends on the case where Gmail is a good example to use a flexible layout but SO is a good example not using it.

Comment: @david: In a fluid layout, my text columns *wouldn't be* 1900px wide unless the user had a good-sized screen and a full-screen browser window, in which case they apparently like reading such wide columns of text or they wouldn't do that. It's up to them. There probably are use cases for fixed-width layout (I'm not *immediately* coming up with one, but...), and obviously there are use cases for fixed-width content *within* a layout, but the vast majority of the fixed layoutsI see are not (IMHO) valid use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Tables are so 1995....

Now you're supposed to use DIVs and SPANs.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

also, w3schools are the normal resource for html starters

but, why bother, you can use an already made layout from websites like:
http://www.freelayouts.com/websites/html-templates

Comment: it can be so hard to get `div`s to work properly, but I'm always so proud of my markup when I'm finished.

Answer (score 4):

Usings DIVs rather than tables would look like this

```
   <div style="width:800px">
     <!-- your content here -->
   </div>
```

This produces on column with the width of 800 pixels. Keep in mind that you normally may put your style definitions in an externals *.css file. In reality you will have some nested DIVs too which hold e.g. your main menu and content e.g.

```
   <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="topMenu">
       <!-- menu items -->
     </div>

     <div id="content">
       <!-- content -->
     </div>
   </div>
```

Here I have used IDs for specific items which can be addressed uniquely. It's easy to assign styles to them via CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width:800px;
}

#topMenu {
  width:800px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Sooner or later you will stumble upon the term "floating divs" which is another big topic.

Comment: +1 But there's no reason for `topMenu` to have the width repeated, is there? As it's a `div`, it'll expand to the full width of its container (one of the things I like about `div` s).